# How to prevent future year in dateTime validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've made a custom date and time validation for an input using jQuery validate plugin and maskedInput plugin.

Is there a way to make in that custom validation, a validation to prevent entering a year bigger than current year?

My code:

```js
$("#date").mask("99/99/9999 99:99", {
  placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
});
$.validator.addMethod("dateTime", function(value, element) {
  var stamp = value.split(" ");
  var validDate = !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(stamp[0]).toString());
  var validTime = /^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/i.test(stamp[1]);
  return this.optional(element) || (validDate && validTime);
}, "Invalid datetime.");

$('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    date: {
      required: true,
      dateTime: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    date: {
      required: ""
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form action='' method='post' id='form'>
  <input type='text' name='date' value='' id='date' placeholder='mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a new method for checking the year

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("minYear", function (value, element) {
    var year = new Date(value).getFullYear();
    var curentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    return this.optional(element) || year <= curentYear;
}, 'Year can not be greater than current year');
```

add the same in the validate rules

```
$('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    date: {
      required: true,
      dateTime: true,
      minYear: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    date: {
      required: ""
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified a bit of your code. Instead of `myDate` should be `year` and added the message for error too, and it works. I didn't even knew till now that you can add multiple custom methods.

Comment: @Ionut Gald it helped . i have fixed that typo .

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own method using [`addMethod`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("minDate", function (value, element) {
    var now = new Date().getFullYear();
    var myDate = new Date(value).getFullYear();
    return this.optional(element) || myDate < now;
});

$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
      date: {
        required: true,
        dateTime: true,
        minDate: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      date: {
        minDate: "The date(year) must not be in the future"
      }
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already have an method that returns true or false, where I make the validation for entire datetime. How would that work in my case?

Comment: Add `.getFullYear()` in front of `Date()` method to take them in year